# TCP communication with step motor

Tags: c#, stream, tcp, device-driver

I have a `class` that I use to communicate with some hardware equipment (a step motor to be precise):

```
public class HdCommunicator : IDisposable
{
    private TcpClient client;
    public HdCommunicator(TcpClient _client)
    {
        client = _client;

        //create and start the listener
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { Listen(); }));
        t.Start();
    }

    public void SendCommand(int data)
    {
        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
        var msgToSend =
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mr " + data + ",1" + Environment.NewLine);
        ns.Write(msgToSend, 0, msgToSend.Length);

        ns.Flush();
    }

    private void Listen()
    {
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead);

                //TODO raise event
                Console.WriteLine("Response: " + response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!client.Connected)
                { /*ignore*/ }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Listener error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

And this is how I currently use it:

```
    static int port = 503;
    static string host = "192.168.33.1";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HdCommunicator comm = new HdCommunicator(new TcpClient(host, port));

        string res = "";
        while (res != "e")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Where to send: ");
            res = Console.ReadLine();

            if (res != "e")
                comm.SendCommand(int.Parse(res));
        }

        comm.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Am I utilizing the `TCP Client` correctly? I'm particularly concerned about the streams' usage and disposing of them. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid that I don't know anything about TCP, but I did notice this.

> ```
>   if (!client.Connected)
>   { /*ignore*/ }
>   else
>   {
>      Console.WriteLine("Listener error: " + ex.Message);
>   }
> ```

Instead of checking for the negative condition, check for the positive. It removes several lines of code and a comment.

```
if(client.Connected)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Listener error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Use the using block

Since your `HDCommunicator` class implements `IDisposable`, you should wrap your code Inside a `using` block, like this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var comm = new HdCommunicator(new TcpClient(host, port)))
    {
        string res = "";
        while (res != "e")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Where to send: ");
            res = Console.ReadLine();

            if (res != "e")
                comm.SendCommand(int.Parse(res));
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

That way, you don't need to manually dispose of your object : the using block does it for you.

### Use string.Empty

I find it cleaner to use `string.Empty` than `""` :

```
string res = string.Empty
```

### Be consistent

To ensure consistency, you should use braces even on conditional statements, like this :

```
if (res != "e")
{
    comm.SendCommand(int.Parse(res));
}
```

### Naming

You should avoid using abreviations or shortened terms and rename `comm` to `hdCommunicator` or `communicator`. Abbreviated variable names are OK when their lifetime is very short, like inside lambda expressions.

Answer (score 4):

```
 Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { Listen(); }));
 t.Start();
```

Because `Listen` takes no parameters, the lambda is unnecessary. You can rewrite as:

```
new Thread(Listen).Start();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just one small comment, I notice you are using:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { Listen(); }));
t.Start();
```

Unless you explicitly need a thread, I believe the preference is to use (the higher level) Task instead, so something like:

```
new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => { Listen(); }));
```

Jon Skeet's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429129/task-vs-thread-differences) explains the reasons for this a lot better than I could.

Quoted:

> Thread is a lower-level concept: if you're directly starting a thread,
>   you know it will be a separate thread, rather than executing on the
>   thread pool etc.
>
> Task is more than just an abstraction of "where to run some code"
>   though - it's really just "the promise of a result in the future". So
>   as some different examples:
>
> Task.Delay doesn't need any actual CPU time; it's just like setting a
>   timer to go off in the future A task returned by
>   WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync won't take much CPU time locally;
>   it's representing a result which is likely to spend most of its time
>   in network latency or remote work (at the web server) A task returned
>   by Task.Run() really is saying "I want you to execute this code
>   separately"; the exact thread on which that code executes depends on a
>   number of factors. Note that the Task abstraction is pivotal to the
>   async support in C# 5.
>
> In general, I'd recommend that you use the higher level abstraction
>   wherever you can: in modern C# code you should rarely need to
>   explicitly start your own thread.

Comment: While generally I would agree, I feel that this is one of the rare cases Jon talks about where threads are relevant. A TCP listener is not the "the promise of a result in the future". It is not semantically a *task*, it doesn't have a defined end, and I don't see why it should waste a threadpool thread for the duration of the listener's existence, when we clearly know it's a `while(true)` loop.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to argue against implementing `IDisposable` here. The class itself does **not** create any `IDisposable` objects - the only one happens to be passed into the constructor. It's a bit of a surprise to have an object used elsewhere be disposed unceremoniously without the caller's knowledge. So, don't implement that interface and let the caller wrap the `new TcpClient(...)` in a `using` construct.

However, in `SendCommand` and `Listen`, `IDisposable` objects pop into being with the call to `GetStream()`. The lifetime of *that* variable needs to be wrapped in `using` to ensure proper deterministic disposal.

```
public class HdCommunicator
{
    private TcpClient client;
    public HdCommunicator(TcpClient _client)
    {
        client = _client;

        //create and start the listener
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { Listen(); }));
        t.Start();
    }

    public void SendCommand(int data)
    {
        using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())
        {
            var msgToSend =
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mr " + data + ",1" + Environment.NewLine);
            ns.Write(msgToSend, 0, msgToSend.Length);

            ns.Flush();
        }
    }

    private void Listen()
    {
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())
                {
                    bytesRead = ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }

                string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead);

                //TODO raise event
                Console.WriteLine("Response: " + response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (client.Connected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Listener error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
static int port = 503;
static string host = "192.168.33.1";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port))
    {
        HdCommunicator comm = new HdCommunicator(tcpClient);

        string res = "";
        while (res != "e")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Where to send: ");
            res = Console.ReadLine();

            if (res != "e")
                comm.SendCommand(int.Parse(res));
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Regarding `IDisposable`: how can you prevent HdCommunicator be initiated like `HdCommunicator comm = new HdCommunicator(new TcpClient(host, port));` ? Wouldn't it be better if the constructor just takes the ip and port and creates the `TcpClient` itself ?

Comment: That's a good point. I suggested the using block because I assumed HdCommunicator.Dispose was actually disposing of the TCPClient object.

Comment: @Heslacher That way I will still have to use the `Dispose` method right?

Comment: @Yoav, yes but than it is a valid to do so, because the communicator creates an `IDisposable` (the TcpClient).

Comment: @Heslacher that would be an all right design, yes. As long as the caller has no other need for the `TcpClient` other than for the `HdCommunicator`. Then, you can create it and `Dispose` of it nicely.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer In regards to the `using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())`, I tried it but I'm getting a `The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets` exception

Answer (score 1):

I've made some changes to my `motor class` based on some of the answers I received here and some additional research and tests. I also changed it so it can be used in a form based application (`WPF` in my case) and this is what I got:

```
public class MotorManager : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler<string> OnMotorMessage;

    private bool showMoves;
    private bool showAllCommands;

    private string ip;
    private int port;

    TcpClient client;
    NetworkStream ns;

    public string MotorName { get; set; }

    public MotorManager(string _ip, int _port, string name, bool showMoves = false, bool showAllCommands = false)
    {
        this.showAllCommands = showAllCommands;
        this.showMoves = showMoves;

        this.MotorName = name;
        this.ip = _ip;
        this.port = _port;

        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
            ns = client.GetStream();
            new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => Listen());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Motor Initialization error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void SendStringCommandToMotor(string command)
    {
        if (showAllCommands)
        {
            OnMotorMessage(this, command);
        }
        SendCommand(command);
    }

    private void SendCommand(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!command.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
                command += Environment.NewLine;

            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);

            if (client.Connected)
            {
                ns.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Send motor command error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Listen()
    {
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = ns.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead);

                //raise the event
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response))
                    OnMotorMessage(this, response.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace(">", ""));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (client.Connected)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Motor listener error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            client.Close();
            ns.Flush();
            ns.Close();
            ns.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Motor dispose error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

This works but I'm still not feeling good with my long lived `NetworkStream` and the fact that I couldn't separate the `SendCommand()` and the `Listener()` into two different `classes` because the `listener` class stooped receiving data when used with a different `TcpClient` instance.
*note - tried to add this as an edit to my original question but it was deleted*